# Micrometer with Spring Boot add custom metrics to count user registrations

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, micrometer, spring-micrometer

What is the best way to go to add custom metrics that count user registrations?
This is the situation:

```
class Registration {
   Long id;
   boolean activated;
}
```

And its repository

```
interface RegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<Registration,Long> { 
    Long countByActivated(boolean isActivated);
}
```

When visiting `http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/user.registrations`

I would like 3 metrics:

1- a metric for all registrations, using `registrationRepository.count()`

2- a metric for activated registrations, using `registrationRepository.countByActivated(true)`: via `http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/user.registrations?tag=activated:true`

3- a metric for non activated registrations, using `registrationRepository.countByActivated(false)`: via `http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/user.registrations?tag=activated:false`

The problem is I can't use the `io.micrometer.core.instrument.Counter` interface because the counter is reseted to 0 when the application is restarted.

What's the best way to go to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `io.micrometer.core.instrument.FunctionCounter`.

You can provide a callback in `FunctionCounter.Builder`:

```java
FunctionCounter counter FunctionCounter.builder(name, meterBean, MeterBean::getValue)
                    .description(description)
                    .baseUnit(unit)
                    .tags(tags)
                    .register(meterRegistry)
        }
```

Where `MeterBean` can be a simple bean like:

```
public interface MeterBean {

    private double value;

    public double getValue() { return this.value };

    public void setValue() { this.value = callTheMethodUWantToSetTheValue() }

}
```

The value is still resetted to 0 when deploying a new version of your application, but you can set the value of this bean at application bootstrap. So this should avoid micrometer to report 0s.